# Работа с датой в SQLITE

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Есть таблица:

[image: Таблица]

Нужно вывести количество записей в 'status_type' 1 и 2 в сутки.

Я написал:

```
SELECT timestamp as 'data',
    sum(case when status_type = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as number_of_new ,
    sum(case when status_type = '2' then 1 else 0 end) as number_of_completed
    FROM incident_table
GROUP BY data
```

Нужен запрос, который возвращает количество задач в статусах 1 и 2 для каждого дня последних 30 дней.

Если одна и та же задача была в разных статусах в один момент (одна и таже дата и секунда), то  то учитывается переход с максимальным `id` записи. Дату вывести в формате: Год/месяц/день.

Comment: Хорошо, с датой без времени я разобрался, SELECT DATE(timestamp), но как посчитать только запись с последним id, если одна и та же задача, была в нескольких статусах в один день

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [DATE()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
select
  date(timestamp) as dt,
  count(case when status_type = '1' then 1 else null end) as number_of_new,
  count(case when status_type = '2' then 1 else null end) as number_of_completed
from incident_table
where timestamp >= (select max(timestamp) - date('now', '-30 days') from incident_table)
group by date(timestamp)
```